# Error:invalid_client - The OAuth client was deleted even after having undeleted the API project

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I am currently facing an issue with my Google API project. This project was deleted yesterday (I don't know who did it...) so I tried to undelete it. After this I still get the same error message:

```
Error: invalid_client
The OAuth client was deleted.

Request detail
cookie_policy_enforce=false
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks
response_type=code
access_type=offline
redirect_uri=https://domain.com/googleConnect
client_id=projectID.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

What can I do to completely revive this API project and fix this issue?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your OAuth client on the [console](https://console.developers.google.com/) got deleted.

You need to restore (if possible) or re-create it.

Dashboard -> Enable APIs and get credentials like keys -> Credentials -> New Credentials -> OAuth Client ID

Add the new client id and Reversed Client id to GoogleService-Info.plist

Finally add com.googleusercontent.apps.YourClientId to URLSchemes

Comment: I have a similar issue but when I try to recreate it I get an error;        Duplicate fingerprint
The fingerprint you specified is already used by an Android OAuth2 client ID in this project or another project

Comment: This might help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160011/the-signing-fingerprint-you-specified-is-already-used-by-another-android-oauth2