# The signing fingerprint you specified is already used by another Android OAuth2 client

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth, oauth2client

Some time ago I created an example project (lets call it "example project") with `Oauth2 client id` for android application in Google APIs console. I also added `SHA1 fingerprint` and package name (for example com.package.name).

My mistake was that an application with same package name already existed. Now I need to create an `Oauth2 client id` for android application in the "valid project" with package name `com.package.name` and with `SHA1 fingerprint` which I added before. Obviously when I tried to add this fingerprint I got an error.

```
The signing fingerprint you specified is already used by another Android OAuth2 client.
```

After that I remembered about "example project" and deleted `client id` from this project. The problem is that I still not able to add this fingerprint for package name `com.package.name`. `Client id` is deleted but still I have the same error as above.

So do I have a possibility to use this fingerprint for the same package name in another project?

Comment: Was this ever resolved? Thanks

Comment: Also encountered same error. Had to remove previously created clientId with same package and fingerprint to get to manage to create new clientId. I've created that clientId even from another google account

Comment: @Robert also faced with this issue... I have deleted my app from one google developer console and create the same app with the same SHA1 and pakeje name on another google dev account... But google still regect me to save credentials...

Comment: Follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60204749/4997704

Comment: I had created an Android OAuth client with the wrong SHA1 key.
Then I tried deleting the wrong OAuth Client, and it's been 12 hours since then.
But I'm still getting the "The signing fingerprint you specified is already used by another Android OAuth2 client" when trying to create a new Android OAuth Client.
Is there another key to be deleted or just the oAuth client?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This error occurs when there is an existing `SIGNING CERTIFICATE FINGERPRINT (SHA1)` on Google Developers linked to a different account.

Solution is to delete the project that is using that `SHA1` in `console.developers.google.com` for the old/incorrect project.

You cannot change the SHA1 fingerprint once it is set.
Remember that deleting the project takes 7 days to completely remove it.

Another option is to delete the `debug.keystore` and generate a new one with:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey
-storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -validity 14000
```

Remember you have to uninstall the app otherwise you get the `[INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]` error.

Comment: so if i want to run more than one app with a debug keystore then that is not possible? Should i use a production keystore in such situation ?

Comment: No, you can use the `debug.keystore` for multiple apps

Comment: Then each app have different debug.keystore? else all apps will produce the same SHA1 key right? its bit confusing for me. please explain

Comment: i am having problem in adding production sha1. even I used it never in google console.

Comment: I don't see an option for deleting the whole client, although I'm concerned what would be the negative affects of deleting the API keys that are on the same page. Even redoing my project with different package names give me the same unusable deleted SHA1 in Gradle signingReport

Comment: Neither waiting for 7 days nor resigning the app is required, just go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials and delete the corresponding OAUTH2 key, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55618235/1033645

Comment: I work on 2 apps with different package names and I still see this issue, as both of them have the same SHA1 value. How come?

Comment: I had created an OAuth client with the wrong SHA1 key. Then I tried deleting the wrong OAuth Client, and it's been 12 hours since then. But I'm still getting the "The signing fingerprint you specified is already used by another Android OAuth2 client" when trying to create a new OAuth Client. Is there another key to be deleted or just the oAuth client?

Answer (score 11):

> The signing fingerprint you specified is already used by another
> Android OAuth2 client

I have to check every project and tried to find another Client ID configured with the SHA1 fingerprint and package name that i tried to configure, unsuccesfully.

**At the end the solution was delete the client ID that i tried to edit and add again with the SHA1 fingerprint and package name, it worked for me:**

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

[image]

Comment: This worked nicely - no editing build.gradle or deleting firebase project or waiting days .. as other answers suggest.  Big thanks for sharing here

Comment: This is the correct answer - neither waiting for several days nor resigning the app is required, just go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials and delete the corresponding OAUTH key.

Comment: I had created an OAuth client with the wrong SHA1 key.
Then I tried deleting the wrong OAuth Client, and it's been 12 hours since then.
But I'm still getting the "The signing fingerprint you specified is already used by another Android OAuth2 client" when trying to create a new OAuth Client.
Is there another key to be deleted or just the oAuth client?

Answer (score 7):

It's late but worth. I have done the same mistake. I added a project to firebase in the wrong account then I deleted and try to add in another firebase account but I couldn't do it because the error indicates that the project is already registered. So it takes time to round about 5 to 7 days to completely delete.

Here is the step I followed to generate another sha1.

> 1. Go to .android in my pc located. C:\Users\shahz.android.
> 2. delete debug.keystore.
> 3. rebuild android project.
> 4. click on signing report (right side bar click gradle,
>      app/task/android/siginingReport)
> 5. you will get a new debug key with new sha1.
> 6. register your app.

Comment: thanks its working and you saved my day brother.

Answer (score 5):

I have faced same problem, its solution is very simple

Go to Console.developer and you can see some auto generated key created with this package. delete that package and add again sha key. hope you will got success. follow this link
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?

Comment: I had created an OAuth client with the wrong SHA1 key.
Then I tried deleting the wrong OAuth Client, and it's been 12 hours since then.
But I'm still getting the "The signing fingerprint you specified is already used by another Android OAuth2 client" when trying to create a new OAuth Client.
Is there another key to be deleted or just the oAuth client?

Comment: delete from firebase as well as from here

Answer (score 4):

If you are using each firebase project for each env as I am, the below approach might be helpful.

In your build gradle, create new application id for each env:

```
productFlavors {
        dev {
            applicationId "se.abc.dev"
        }
        stag {
            applicationId "se.abc.stag"
        }
        prod
    }
```

On each firebase project, add a new project with corresponding application id with the same finger print. Remember to download the new google service json file since the application id was changed. The package name remains the same so it would not be a problem when uploading into google play. But for sure, I leave the prod flavor empty, so the package name and application id will be the same for prod release to avoid trouble.

Answer (score 1):

As someone could wanna use the same application through two or more firebase projects for many reasons and so get this error I here do address this particular scenario. The esiest way to run the same application upon two or more different firebase projects (let’s say production and staging) is to add to your Module level `build.gradle` file a build variant (let's say staging) like this one:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mydomain.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 18
        versionName "2.8"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        staging {
            initWith debug
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
            versionNameSuffix = "-staging"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    [...]
}

// Firebase
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In the build variant `staging` what's most important is the line:

```
applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
```

This will inject at build time a ".staging" suffix to your application ID so that you will automatically have

```
applicationId "com.mydomain.myapp.staging"
```

You than need to add this application (`"com.mydomain.myapp.staging"`) to your firebase staging project and so you will be able to add the same `"com.mydomain.myapp"` **SHA1** to this application, because it has a different application ID.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue today. As the project takes a long time to get completely deleted, the easiest way is to create a new SHA1 by simply deleting the local **debug.keystore**. It get's auto generated when you run any app after deleting it. This is documented in the Android docs [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#debugmode).

Answer (score 1):

I'll note that this if your app is listed in the play store, you probably don't want to change the package name and you probably don't want to replace the production key (as you'll be forced to make a new listing).

If you're absolutely sure that there are no currently active projects making use of the current package-name/fingerprint pair, one final thing to try: **Make a completely new credential.** You'll have to replace your credential file in the application.

I didn't expect this to help, but it did.  Maybe Google is somehow caching the lookup? "This packagename/fingerprint/clientID lookup is a duplicate, so don't bother looking it up again."

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it occurs becuase you have linked the app with **Google Cloud Platform** project for an *API* like *Google Signin*. So firebase shows OAUTH2 issues. At one time either you can use Auth service by firebase or gcp.

Possible Solution: Try to remove the **Google Cloud Platform** or create a new Android Project in **Android Studio**.