# SHA1 fingerprint already used by another OAuth2 client

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform, sha1

Some time ago I created a project in Google Developers Console with Oauth2 client id for android app with package name and SHA1 fingerprint. Somehow the project got created without project id, which prevented me from deploying it to App Engine. I deleted the project, recreated it and now trying to add a new client id with the same package name and SHA1 fingerprint. A month after deleting the original project I'm getting "The signing fingerprint you specified is already used by another Android OAuth2 client".
Is there a way to reuse package name and SHA1 fingerprint with the new project?

Comment: See answer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60204749/4997704

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't sound like a SO resolvable issue.

It seems like your SHA1 fingerprint is still associated with a deleted project (which is probably in limbo). Google Support is the only one who can help you.