# SHA-1 already used Google Sign In

Tags: android, google-signin

We are trying to release Google Sign In in android app. Then we tested the app in using debug keystore it works fine. But when trying to release to production we were adding release SHA1 [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In) but unable to add with following error:

> The SHA-1 you specified is already used with the same package name for
>   a different Android OAuth2 client.

But it create Android Key & WebClient but not AndroidClient.

But We are sure that there we have deleted all the ClientIDs in all three accounts and tried adding it. But same error. Checked all the projects multiple times but in vain.

Also checked all the questions on SO but no solution. Please help.

Comment: anybody here who knows the answer.

Comment: Unable to add credentials even today.

Comment: I have already upploaded the APK earlier with same .jks key. At that time we are not using the Google SignIn.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I'm facing the same issue. :|

Comment: @PratikStephen its so old question as I don't even remember what was exact problem & was it resolved or not.

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer:

[The signing fingerprint you specified is already used by another Android OAuth2 client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160011/the-signing-fingerprint-you-specified-is-already-used-by-another-android-oauth2)

> Remember that deleting the project takes 7 days to completely remove
>   it.

Also mentioned in Google support article:

https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787

Comment: Actually we have not deleted any project. But deleted the client ids within projects. Deletion of client ids is instant task, so this should not be the case.