# Find out which cloud project claimed an app fingerprint

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

When creating a client ID for Android in the Google Cloud Platform developer console, I get the following popup:

> The fingerprint you specified is already used by an Android OAuth2
>   client ID in this project or another project

I probably need to find that project and add it as a client of my project. How can I find out which project it is?

Edit: it has been proposed that this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39807959/407058). In that case, the other project is known already, and the asker wants to know why deleting the other project takes some time to take effect. That is not the same. I'm trying to find the other project.

There are several other questions referencing this error, but none have asked how to find the project that claimed the client id.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a client ID from your project but not the other way around since client ID is a private information

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I was not able to identify and find the problem project.

After getting this error I spent 4 hours checking all my accounts, all projects in them and than checking it again. I have even asked all developers in my team if they had created any keys for our package name. Nothing helped. Finally I have found a project hidden on "All projects" tab containing the client id I was searching for.

Comment: I work in a large organization where I don't have access to view all the projects.

Comment: @philo The problem occurs only in case when BOTH SHA1 and package name coincide. So I suppose normally the person who has access to the publish key should have access to the publish google account. And this account is the place where Google Cloud project should be located. If you are not that person and you are trying to setup the client_id on your account you should ask the person with access to that publish account instead to add the key. Anyway you should ask all persons who has access to your key to check their accounts.