# Is it possible to generate another SHA1 key from the same computer for Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am currently trying to implement Google Sign in with Firebase on Android and it requires to generate SHA1 key which I already did, but then for some reason I deleted the firebase project. So the first project had a pair with the first SHA1 and package name.Then I tried to add firebase to the project again and this time used the same package name and the same SHA1 so Firebase didn't allow me to do that. It says that the pair with the same package name and SHA1 exists with other project and I wonder if I could generate another SHA1 from the same computer. Is this ever possible? Or if you generated once that's it and nothing can be done? What workaround is possible in my situation? Changeing package name is also not desirable and I will leave it as a last option.
For making it more clear see the shot below:
[image]

Comment: @sunflower20 Did you checkout this existing link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807959/an-oauth2-client-already-exists-for-this-package-name-and-sha-1-in-another-proje?rq=1

Comment: @MarkKeen for Google Sign in its not optional, it won't work

Documentation says:

If you haven't yet specified your app's SHA-1 fingerprint, do so from the Settings page of the Firebase console. See Authenticating Your Client for details on how to get your app's SHA-1 fingerprint.

Comment: @MarkKeen okay I can omit but Google Sign in won't work, you can omit it if you do simple email, password sign in, and error message says like that because it doesn't know which sign in I am implementing, but Google sign in does require it and I am not going to argue on that anymore

Comment: @strike thank you very much and thank you for not marking as dublicate I really haven't came up with that answer. Generating new SHA1 seemed a bit messy at first sight, do you know some straightforward guide? Meantime I will try to do it as it described in the documentation.

Comment: I thought that this link is also very useful and worth to be here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160011/the-signing-fingerprint-you-specified-is-already-used-by-another-android-oauth2