# An OAuth2 client already exists for this package name and SHA-1 certificate in another project

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-play-console

I've already deployed an app using Firebase and Flutter on App Store and Google Play.
I am currently working on a big update, so I create a new firebase project to have a new configuration with a new firestore database.

The problem is that I can't add SHA1 fingerprint from Google Play in the new firebase project because it's already used by the first project I created which support my current app in production.
[image]

I tried to add to the whitelist the client IDs of external projects in Google Provider settings in Firebase Authentication but it solve my problem : I still can't login with google in by new version app.

So I think I have two other possibilities :

- I edit my package name but I am not okay for my new version to appear as a new app and not an update.
- I edit SHA-1 but the current app in production won't work anymore.

I have no clue how to bypass this problem. What can I do ?

Comment: Did you check these threads: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160011/the-signing-fingerprint-you-specified-is-already-used-by-another-android-oauth2), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807959/an-oauth2-client-already-exists-for-this-package-name-and-sha-1-in-another-proje)? Do they answer your question?

Comment: Hello @FaridShumbar, Yes I checked these threads. I've already tried to generate a new keystore but it's not possible to upload an App Bundle with a different signature from the previous uploads. I think the only solution is to update my app without Google signin, few days after the release I will delete by old project so I can use my SHA1 fingerprint.