# Delete Google Cloud Project

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I shutdown my google project as I want to use package name of android app for authentication in another google cloud project. But after 20 days also project is not deleted. I don't want to change my SHA 1 Key or package name.

So is there any alternative way to add package name on that cloud project?

When will shutdown google cloud project will be deleted?

After project deleted am I able to use that package name in another project with same SHA1 Key?
I am getting popup message when I am trying to register package name and SHA 1.

```
The fingerprint that you specified is already being used by an Android OAuth2 client ID in this project or another project.
```

Comment: Please see this SO post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160011/the-signing-fingerprint-you-specified-is-already-used-by-another-android-oauth2/29279091

Answer (score 0):

Just go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials and delete the corresponding OAUTH2 key. You don't need to change the package name or certificate of your app, or to wait for 7 days until Google permanently removes the project you've deleted.