# Not able to create client ID for Android "Google Calendar Api" integration

Tags: android, google-api, google-developers-console, google-calendar-api

I am integrating Google Calendar API for my android app. While creating the clientId for my release build, I am blocked with the error;

> "Duplicate fingerprint
>   The fingerprint you specified is already used by an Android OAuth2 client ID in this project or another project"

**My debug build**

Eg :- Package name is say "com.example.myapp.dev", 
I have enabled the "Google Calendar API", by creating the clientId with SHA1 keyprint generated by my debug keystore.
Here everything works fine.

**My release build**

Eg :- Package name is say "com.example.myapp"
When I am trying to enable the "Google Calendar API", I was stopped with the above error.

I cant find who created a clientID before, by using this package name. Also I cant change the package name, because the app is already available in playstore over years.
How can I solve this issue, Can somebody please help resolving this issue. I am blocked on this now.

**Additional information:**

I am changing the package name using "applicationIdSuffix" from the gradle script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The signing fingerprint you specified is already used by another Android OAuth2 client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160011/the-signing-fingerprint-you-specified-is-already-used-by-another-android-oauth2)

Comment: @DaImTo have deleted the clientId created in other project in the google API console. Still I was stuck with this issue. The issue is resolved now, by using a different google account I am able to create a clientID.  Thanks for the help.