# How to create the SHA 1 finger print to generate the client id and api key?

Tags: android

I am facing the issue in creating the client id but i created the api key for my project. When i create the o auth client id

`"The fingerprint that you specified is already being used by an Android OAuth2 client ID in this project or another project."`

This notification is showing.How to create the client id fopr my project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160011/the-signing-fingerprint-you-specified-is-already-used-by-another-android-oauth2

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya      sha 1 finger print  same for all project or new sha 1 finger print is used for all new projects ??