# Android Firebase push notification with new sha1

Tags: android, firebase

I'm updating an android App, here previous developer used firebase for push notification and I have access the account. When I'm updating the app with new computer is it mandatory to add *sha1 key* of my computer in firebase account or google json file, because I cant add multple keys. help me please.your help will be apreciated

Comment: you can delete the sha1 key and create new one and upload that in firebase @Irshad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another sha-1 key like this:

Go to firebase console and follow these steps:

In your project click `setting->project setting`

In "your app tab" click add fingerprint and add your sha-1

[image]

And you can add multiple keys to your project like this.

Comment: an auth2 client already exist for this package name and ShA 1 in another project

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160011/the-signing-fingerprint-you-specified-is-already-used-by-another-android-oauth2)