# Firebase/Flutter google-services.json conflicts

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

After I lost my access credentials to my old firebase account (rookie mistake I know but things happen!) that already has Google Auth enabled and linked with the SHA1 fingerprint I set up a new account and enabled the Google Auth using SHA256 fingerprint this time because it wouldn't let me use the same SHA1 and the same package name twice then I switched the files `google-services.json` and `GoogleService-Info.plist`.

When I tried to test adding a document to a collection in firestore, I get no errors or warnings in the console but the firestore console doesn't show the added documents as well, it does not seem that there is something wrong with the code.

My question is how to know if there are any conflicts what-so-ever? is there some kind of way to know which account is currently linked to the app ?

Comment: Do you run flutter clean after the new account connected..?

Comment: @TharakaDayanjana no I didn't actually

Comment: @TharakaDayanjana so I ran `flutter clean` but now I can't sign in at all and this is what I get instead is the login result returns NULL

Comment: I think that might be a problem with your .json file.  do you add SHA 1 key correctly..?

Comment: as I mentioned above I used SHA256 instead because I couldn't add SHA1 twice

Comment: oh, I just realized that SHA-256 doesn't work with OAuth2

Comment: @TharakaDayanjana do you have any other alternatives to this? I can't log in my old account that has the SHA1 enabled

Comment: the only way I know is deleting the project. but your case can't do it. sorry

Comment: Another option is to delete the debug.keystore and generate a new one with:

keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey
-storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -validity 14000
Remember you have to uninstall the app otherwise you get the [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE] error.   follow this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160011/the-signing-fingerprint-you-specified-is-already-used-by-another-android-oauth2

Comment: @TharakaDayanjana the app is not on Play Store yet to do that

Comment: Although it might be possible to follow the path that you're following, it might be better to start a recovery process for your account, with [firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support), so you can get back everything back and from my point of view it will require less effort than what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project is `NOT` listed on Google Play Store `AND` the package is still `NOT` that important in your work flow create a new project with other package name and reset your package name across the files in your flutter project as you would normally do