# APP Engine: The OAuth client was deleted?

Tags: google-app-engine

I deploy a node project to APP Engine, and I can use it normally, but when I try to turn on the IAP, some issues arise:

```
Error: deleted_client

The OAuth client was deleted.

Request Details
client_id=252592340030-jcass7dq1dnc1ia8is9aic1m7g1bnemq.apps.googleusercontent.com
response_type=code
scope=openid email
redirect_uri=https://iap.googleapis.com/v1/oauth/clientIds/252592340030-jcass7dq1dnc1ia8is9aic1m7g1bnemq.apps.googleusercontent.com:handleRedirect
code_challenge=DPS4im9C-3zJSkHAg7zhvht9WfvIbrrPJ3eUh6dqKAw
code_challenge_method=S256
cred_ref=true
state=eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6InpRSk45dyJ9.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_OaFx1MDAxY1Jl-Db2pGBcdTAwMTMyXHUwMDI2U5GoXHUwMDFlcJdcdTAwMDa6-1x1MDAwMMWVcd06hTso-WLFXHUwMDAwuFx1MDAxYot9tYBt-SzbXCJcdTAwMTX5XHUwMDE0vElcdTAwMGK2iZ3qXHUwMDFmxO_KnbgsxiJ9.xH30mwUXqnoLxlVfmzw_BYHEB13gbMcY18O6A_fHxH29uTl9d9C-RgW1RpSNRjXJ3ak4gDQ7r00BJSaqf7F06Q
```

Someone can take a look? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another thread that seems to handle the `The OAuth client was deleted` error.

[Error:invalid_client - The OAuth client was deleted even after having undeleted the API project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253508/errorinvalid-client-the-oauth-client-was-deleted-even-after-having-undeleted)