# Google Cloud: OAuth Access stopped working

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-storage

I get the following error on my Google cloud account if I try to authenticate via oauth2.

> 401. That’s an error.
>
> Error: deleted_client
>
> The OAuth client was deleted.

It used to work for over 2 years now. I did not have changed anything.

How can I repair this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your OAuth client got deleted from your console, there's a similar question regarding this issue in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253508/errorinvalid-client-the-oauth-client-was-deleted-even-after-having-undeleted). You can check that by heading to the APIs & Services menu, under the Credentials topic.

Quoting the provided solution there:

> You need to restore (if possible) or re-create it.
>
> Dashboard -> Enable APIs and get credentials like keys -> Credentials -> New Credentials -> OAuth Client ID
>
> Add the new client id and Reversed Client id to GoogleService-Info.plist
>
> Finally add com.googleusercontent.{apps.YOUR_CLIENT_ID} to URLSchemes

Comment: Thanks! Where is the "GoogleService-Info.plist" located? I am in a Ubuntu VM.

Comment: That's inside your project when using the Firebase Oauth client. I guess that's not what you are looking for. As you are using an Ubuntu VM, the issue has to be withing the Console UI. Are you able to see in the Credentials menu if the OAuth access is still there?